# Gorilla websocket client read message error

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have a client websocket code look like this

```
c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("<url>", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go func() {
        defer close(clientResponse)
        for {
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error reading: ", err)
                break
            }
            clientResponse <- message
            fmt.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()
```

What happened is after I stop writing messages to the server side, my client throw this error which come from the `ReadMessage` method:

`websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF`

Anyone know where is this error come from and how to fix it ?. So far all I can think of is the server/client have a Read/Write deadline and after that, it just auto disconnect

Comment: This error comes from the server (or a proxy to the server) closing the connection.  There's insufficient information to answer why the server closes the connection.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that the server side is belong to a third party. I just connect to them, so I'm trying to figure it out the problem is from the client side or server side

Comment: Does the server require the application to send messages to keep the connection open?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have no idea because I don't have codebase of the server side. But so far, I think it does

Comment: More detail: the 1006 error is returned when read on the connection unexpectedly returns io.EOF.  The io.EOF error is returned when the peer (the server in this case) closes the connection.  The io.EOF error is only expected after the peer cleanly closes the connection by sending a close frame.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks for your help. I think so too, and if that's the case then nothing I can do but open a new connection which is kinda costly ...

Comment: @CeriseLimón I think what I can do is to send a ping message after like 15-30 second to maintain the connection between client and server

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` means you are at end of the file and you can't read anymore, you can add `err == io.EOF` into your codes, it works. The complete code is as follows:

```
c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("<url>", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
go func() {
    defer close(clientResponse)
    for {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
            log.Fatal("Error reading: ", err)
            break
        }
        clientResponse <- message
        fmt.Printf("recv: %s", message)
    }
}()
```

Comment: Hmm perhaps I didn't let you know what I want clear enough. What I want is to hold that connection forever (like chat messages) , because after writing a bunch of messages to the server and get result from `ReadMessage`, my client throw that error. So if the next time I want to write messages, I have to open the websocket connection again and I don't want that

Comment: @QuangVõ If the server closes the connection, then you have no choice but to open a new connection.  A robust application will be written to handle this situation.

Comment: The error is a `*weboscket.CloseError`, not io.EOF.  Use `websocket.IsCloseError(err, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure)` to test for the error in the question. That said, all errors should be handled identically in the OP's scenario: close the current connection and open a new connection.

Comment: You can use for loop to keep the connection to the server,  maybe the client will be closed because of error, and you can't write message again, I don't know how to describe it clearly, you can  catch the error at first.

Comment: @EricPen like a for loop to send ping messages after 15-30 sec ?